# onLocationChange() not getting called? Calculate Distance Travelled -Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps, location

I have this code:

```
Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
Location oldLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
float distanceTravelled=0;
```

onLocationChanged:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    oldLocation.set(newLocation);
    startactivity();
    distanceTravelled+=newLocation.distanceTo(oldLocation);
    String stringDistance= Float.toString(distanceTravelled);
    TextView distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDistance);
    distance.setText(stringDistance);
}
```

startactivity:

```
public void startactivity() 
{
    GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(Live.this);

    if(gps.canGetLocation())
    {
        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is: \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        newLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
        newLocation.setLongitude(longitude);    
    }
    else
    {
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }

}
```

GPSTracker is a separate class which gets the current latitude and longitude (it is working fine!).

GPS updates at min. distance 5 metres and min. time 5 seconds.

Here is my full GPSTracker class: ***[GPSTracker.java](http://pastebin.com/B5TWTNq8)***

I have added the three permissions in the manifest: fine,coarse and internet.

My problem is the textview inside onLocationChanged never gets changed.

What is the problem? Is onLocationChanged not getting called or there is some logical error (distance always remains zero)?

And how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
```

but you are not using that parameter anywhere in the function.
It looks like you should add

```
newLocation.set(location);
```

after the first line of your function.

At the moment you are calculating the distance between the starting point and itself, and that will always be 0.

Comment: Seems correct logically,do you think it will work? I can't test it now.Will the textView update whenever the location will change?
Do I need to call that startactivity also?

Comment: I don't think you need to call `startactivity()` in `onLocationChanged`, starting the activity once should be enough.